# File can be opened in FTP but not in HTTP after upload from site

Tags: php, forms, http, ftp

I am writing a PHP script that enables a user to upload a picture and then displays it on their page. Everything works fine up until the part where they need to display it. I run the form and submit it and the picture shows up in the directory in my FTP. I can download that file from the FTP and view it on my computer. I can visit the FTP url of that image, login and see it fine.

When I go to the HTTP version of the exact same URL, I get a 404 error. I have checked the permissions on the folder and it's ok to read and write for a user. I even checked the permissions on the file itself after it's uploaded and it's fine. Here's my PHP code when uploading the file:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
if($_POST['submit']){
//GET FILE ATTRIBUTES
$name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];

if ($name){
//start upload process
$location = "pics/$name";
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$location);

$sql = "UPDATE tbl_name SET imagelocation='$location' WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

header('location:profile.php');
}
else{
die("Please select a file! <a href='profile.php'>GO BACK</a>");
}
}
?>
```

Any idea what this could be? I haven't seen this problem before.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Where is the "pics/" folder located. Is it under any available location of the web server?

Comment: I am using GoDaddy. @JScoobyCed, what do you mean by 'any available location'? It's a subdirectory of the site I'm working on if that helps answer it at all.

Comment: I meant, is the "pics" folder available through HTTP (i.e. something like "http:// www.yoursite.com /pics"

Comment: Yeah it is, it's basically exactly that structure for the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think folder permission may not be right when you created the folder with mkdir(). hope setting right permission will solve the problem.

Comment: I just realized that using mkdir() I set the file permission at 0700 which prevented from read/write permissions on that folder. I've set it to 0777 now and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

It works now. I deleted the folder and recreated the folder with the same name. The folder was initially created through mkdir in PHP so I'm sure that had something to do with it. If anybody has any insight into why the folder wouldn't work with mkdir, feel free to post here. Thanks!